# how to decode/ get encoding of file (Power BI desktop file)

Tags: java, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I am having power BI desktop report(pbix) internal file (DataMashup), which i am trying to decode.
My Aim is to create Power-BI desktop report, Data Model using any programming language. I am using Java for initial.

[image]

files are  encoded with some encoding technique.

I tried to get encoding of file and it is returning windows 1254. but decoding is not happening.

```
File f = new File("example.txt");

    String[] charsetsToBeTested = {"UTF-8", "windows-1254", "ISO-8859-7"};

    CharsetDetector cd = new CharsetDetector();
    Charset charset = cd.detectCharset(f, charsetsToBeTested);

    if (charset != null) {
        try {
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), charset);
            int c = 0;
            while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char)c);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            fnfe.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }else{
        System.out.println("Unrecognized charset.");
    }
```

Unzipping of file is also not working

```
public void unZipIt(String zipFile, String outputFolder)
{
    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
    try
    {
        File folder = new File(outputFolder);
        if(!folder.exists())
        {
            folder.mkdir();
        }
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
        System.out.println(zis);

        System.out.println(zis.getNextEntry());
        for(ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry(); ze != null; ze = zis.getNextEntry())
        {
            String fileName = ze.getName();
            System.out.println(ze);
            File newFile = new File((new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(outputFolder))).append(File.separator).append(fileName).toString());
            System.out.println((new StringBuilder("file unzip : ")).append(newFile.getAbsoluteFile()).toString());
            (new File(newFile.getParent())).mkdirs();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            int len;
            while((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) 
            {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            fos.close();
        }

        zis.closeEntry();
        zis.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The file contains a binary header and then XML with UTF-8 specified.
The header data seems to hold the file name (Config/Package.xml), so assuming a zip format is understandable. With a zip format also there would be binary data at the end of file.

Maybe the file was downloaded using FTP, and a text conversion ("\n" to "\r\n") was done. Then the zip would be corrupted. Renaming the file to .zip might help testing the file with zip tools.

**Try first the .tar format.** This would be logical as the XML file is not compressed. Add .tar to the file ending.

Otherwise, if the content is always UTF-8 XML:

```
Path f = Paths.get("example.txt");
String start ="<?xml";
String end = ">";
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(f);
String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1); // Single byte encoding.
int startI = s.indexOf(start);
int endI = s.lastIndexOf(end) + end.length();
//bytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, startI, endI);
String xml = new String(bytes, startI, endI - startI, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: This file has no extension, I can unzip using 7z software but not with winrar. I am not able to zip it again after change in file and after unzip this file i am getting Config folder, Formula folder and one xml file. All sub files content is different.

Comment: If I will do any changes in xml of DataMashup file and create packaged power bi report file (pbix) it will throw error saying file is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the System.IO.Packaging library to extract the Power BI data mashup. It uses the OPC package standard, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/august/opc-a-new-standard-for-packaging-your-data).